# Points on a plane

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

I have been assigned this problem and am not sure how to approach it! Please help me figure out what I should do!

Let $S$ be a finite set of points in a plane chosen to have the property that for each $P\in S$ there is exactly one point $Q_P \in S \setminus \{P\}$ nearest to $P$.

Join each point $P$ of $S$ to the point $Q_P$. Prove the following:

1. The diagram obtained contains no closed polygon.
2. No two of the lines cross each other.
3. No one point is joined to more than 5 other points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Suppose it does. Let $A_i$ be the series of points, such that $A_{i+1}$ is the closest point to $A_i$. Consider the implications on the distances $A_i A_{i+1}$ and $A_{i-1} A_i$. Hence, reach a contradiction.

**Hint 2:** Suppose it does. Let the 4 points be A, B, C, D, where $B$ is the closest point to $A$ and $D$ is the closest point to $C$. Show that $AB + CD > AC + BD$ by the triangle inequality. Hence, reach a contradiction.

**Hint 3:** Suppose it does. Let the vertex point be $A$, let the other points it is connected to be $A_i$, labelled in a clockwise manner. Show that $A_i A A_{i+1} > 60^\circ$. Hence, reach a contradiction.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Since I don't know much on the topic (these problems are given to me weekly in university and they cover a vast span of mathematic knowledge and sometimes they are topics I have never studied!) could you suggest some links I could use to read more about it? thank you so much